# Win8 Share Contract with Portable Class Library

Tags: mvvm, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

I am trying to receive shared text in a windows 8 store application via the share contract.  I can receive the text, but if the text makes its way into an observable collection I get a com exception.  How do I receive shared text and pass it off correctly to a viewmodel in a portable class library?

Portable class library:

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
        };
    }
}
```

Locator.cs:

```
public class Locator
{
    private static ViewModel vm;
    public static ViewModel VM
    {
        get
        {
            if (vm == null)
            {
                vm = new ViewModel();
            }
            return vm;
        }
    }
}
```

Store App Project:

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page...>
    <Page.Resources>
        <vm:Locator x:Key="Locator"/>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid ... DataContext="{Binding VM, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}" .../>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

App.xaml.cs (abbreviated):

```
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    base.OnShareTargetActivated(args);
    if (args.ShareOperation.Data.AvailableFormats.Contains("Text"))
    {
        var text = await args.ShareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();
        Locator.VM.Strings.Add(text);
    }
}
```

The last line above ( Locator.VM.Strings.Add(text) ) throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler'
>   to class type
>   'System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler'.
>   Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to
>   types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast
>   to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports
>   QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

Comment: I did some more testing and it seems the portable class library is not important - exception happens anytime an observable collection bound to a view is modified in this method.

Comment: Replicated in fresh MVVM Light-based project in Windows 8.1 / Visual Studio 2012.  Also unable to bypass using Dispatcher / Tasks.

Comment: Try creating a method in your VM that adds the string from inside the PCL.

Comment: I tried that early on and it had no effect.  As commented above, I have since moved everything into one store app project - the PCL is not needed to reproduce.

Comment: It looks like you have another `NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler` class declared somewhere. Have you created a custom `ObservableCollection`? Maybe a reference library has one?

Comment: No.  My latest project is [new store app-> mvvm light -> add observable collection to VM -> Add share contract -> OnShareActivated adds text to OC].  Works if the app is not running and share happens, dies if it is already running.  Almost looks like there are two COM apartments, one for share activation and one for user activation.

Comment: Any chance you could fire up a repro and file over at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio?